# Can Java's instanceof differentiate functionally identical classes?

Tags: java, instanceof

So let's say I have two nearly identical classes, however they represent objects with key differences. At the moment, those differences aren't really implemented.

So for instance, one class, we'll call it `MorningShiftWorker`, has the exact same methods and same constructor as another, which we'll call `EveningShiftWorker`. Objects of both of these are stored in a list of their supertype `ShiftWorker`.

Logically, it makes sense to separate these two groups, but rather than add additional variables to the mix, I figured I'd just do a check on objects in the `ShiftWorker` list using `instanceof`.

My question is: Is `instanceof` smart enough to differentiate apples from oranges? These two classes are at the moment identical in all but name. Is that enough for `instanceof` to tell them apart, or is there another way I should go about this?

Comment: Why don't you simply try it?

Comment: they are define in two separate class files, neither one  inherit from another one, hence one is not instance of another

Comment: This sounds like it's going to have some serious modeling issues. You should almost never need to use `instanceof` if your domain model is constructed properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `instanceof` essentially checks to see if the object can be properly cast to the given class. Suppose we have these classes:

```
public class Fruit {}
public class Orange extends Fruit {}
public class Apple extends Fruit {}
```

Then in some method we try:

```
Fruit f = new Apple();
boolean isOrange = f instanceof Orange; //False
```

This also works for empty/non-functional interfaces.

Comment: I've heard that using instanceof is poor code design as well. Are there alternative approaches I should be studying as well? Also, thank you! I should have just tested it but it's been a stressful week and I'm not quite on the ball yet today!

Comment: @TheFunk take a look at the [visitor pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm) but in your example say you had a calcPay() that was implemented differently in the base classes you could call it polymorphically from your list not need for visitor or instanceof

Comment: @TheFunk `instanceof` does not inherently mean bad design. What I do feel is bad design is when programmers design their logic based around the ability to use `instanceof`. There are a lot of OOP paradigms (e.g. overloading) and design patterns (e.g. interpreter, facade) which can much more cleanly overcome the problem of "exactly what kind of object is this reference pointing to". In essence: Don't be afraid to use it, but also don't expect to use it.

Comment: @PSD that's exactly what I have going on. Exactly the same method with different implementations based on the subclass. In some cases however I simply need to exempt certain employees from certain things. For example if I want to send an update to all employees but only those that are supposed to be on duty, I could use instanceof to determine whether an employee should be on duty and thus should receive the message.

Comment: @TheFunk in the example you ave above im assuming that `onDuty` is a boolean? if thats the case I don't think you need instanceof.  If your working off the time of day to determine if employees are working then I think a signature like `void update(Date date)` the let each class determine if they are 'on duty'.  This makes the adding of new employee classes cleaner (IMO) than using instanceof in your example. As Zircon pointed out there are times when its a good idea to use instanceof so I don;t think an 'avoid at all costs' approach is necessary but in your example I think there is better way

Answer (score 3):

The `instanceof` operator doesn't compare the contents of the classes. It knows very well whether `x` is instanceof `y` or not, even if `x` and `y` are identical classes except for the name.

It only checks whether the first parameter is in the inheritance hierarchy of the second parameter, i.e. everything is `instanceof Object`, `Integer`, `Float` and its friends are `instanceof Number` and of course `x instanceof y` for all objects `x` of type `y`.

Comment: "`x instanceof x`" This doesn't make sense for any `x`. If `x` is a value, it can't be the right of `instanceof`; if it's a type, it can't be on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the wrong question. You should be asking: "how do I fix my broken design".

If you have to classes that are "nearly" identical, but share "duplicated" code within their methods and constructors; then you are doing something **wrong**.

**Never ever** duplicate code.

So, instead of worrying about instanceof; you should step back and re-design your class hierarchy to find means how you can end up with a **common** implementation of the **common** things; so that your morning and evening shifters only contain "those different aspects".

You might want to check out "Agile principles" by Robert Martin. That book contains a nice real-world example on a "payment system"; and explains in great detail how you create a system in which you have employees that are paid in very different models - without duplicating stuff all over the place. (you can even find the "C#" version as PDF for free on the internet).

Comment: Thanks. At the moment the classes are functionally identical but they do not contain common code in actuality. In talking with @PSD below I was reminded of polymorphism. If I make my superclass have abstract methods, I can define them in my subclasses but call them on the superclass without ever using instanceof! :D

Comment: Yes, that is how things should be.

Answer (score 0):

yes instanceof is "smart" enough, since java uses name for differentiating objects/classes not structure